# Varnish Cache installed but not Starting error cannot open socket: 6081 Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: centos, varnish

I have successfully installed latest version of Varnish (varnish.x86_64 0:4.1.3-1.el6) along with its dependency as outlined in official website of Varnish.

Now, I am trying to start varnish cache by `/etc/init.d/varnish start` and also tried `service varnish start` but I am getting errors - *starting varnish cache: error: cannot open socket: 6081: Address family not supported by protocol [FAILED]*

I am on VPS server using CentOS, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.27 also using X-Mod-Pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0
Please suggest how can I overcome the error.

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you running? what's the content of your /etc/varnish/varnish.params and /usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service ?

Comment: CentOS version- 6.8 x86_64, varnish.params and varnish.service shows "No such files or directory".

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann I appreciate your effort to help me. I have solved my issue. First I "erase" varnish and then "remove" varnish. I found that my server already have varnish package 2.0 (old version), so I installed the old version and "start" it. It started. Now I downloaded the new varnish package (4.1) and "upgrade" the old one. And it works.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Happy caching!